# When using Shell in Windows, how to solve "sh: D:/DevTools/Git/root/restart_all.sh: No such file or directory"?

Tags: windows, bash, shell, powershell, docker

I've wrote a shell script file on mac to deploy some docker application. But when I copy it to Windows10, it seems that it cannot run properly.

The path after "docker exec xx /foo/bar" is always transferred into an absolute path in windows, and leads to an error like: "sh: D:/DevTools/Git/root/start_zk.sh: No such file or directory".

What's more, when executing "docker exec xx /foo/bar" in powershell or git bash, it can run properly. This problem only occurs when I write it into a file, and run it through "sh deploy.sh".

I've tried to add "\" before "/", but it doesn't help. My code is listed below.

```sh
echo "deploying zookeepers..."
docker exec ac sh /root/start_zk.sh
```

Is there any fault in my script? The command "sh /root/start_zk.sh" after "docker exec" should be a parameter for the docker container to execute, but it seems that it is recognized by windows as a command or path. Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Normally you should set things up so that `docker run` starts everything needed in a container on its own, and that there's one process per container.  Running `docker exec` to start a service (and for that matter one that has [a standard image](https://hub.docker.com/_/zookeeper)) suggests the startup sequence needs to be refactored.

Comment: Thx, it's a good advice. It's just I haven't finished developing and some details may be changed later, so I'm writing those script to simplify the start procedure. The same problem occurs when I use "docker run" with a command following such as "/bin/bash", and the error disappears when I only use "bash", which confuse me. So I'm wondering whether there are something wrong in my script. Or it's just a strange difference of shell between windows and unix?